# Error ORA-00906 in CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting the error `ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis` in the following code:

```
create table "employee_copy" (
   employee_id number(10), 
   first_name VARCHAR2, 
   last_name VARCHAR2, 
   email VARCHAR2, 
   phone_number VARCHAR2, 
   hire_date date, 
   job_id VARCHAR2, 
   salary number(10), 
   commission_pct number(3,3), 
   manager_id number(10),
   department_id number(10)
)
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to a) have relevant information in the title ("what is wrong in this code here" is going to mean absolutely nothing to future users of this site who see it in a search result, and it says nothing about the problem you're having), and b) explain what the problem is you're having with what you've posted. What error message are you getting? In what way is it "wrong"?  If you want help, *give us the info you have right in front of you*. You're asking us for *free help* to solve **your** problem, so you should make it as easy on us as possible to give you that help.

Comment: Just as a side note - quote identifiers such as `"employee_copy"` are a Really Bad Idea. Yes, this allows a database to have a mixed-or-lower-case name - but as Oracle set unquoted names to UPPER_CASE even if given in lower case, use of quotes when creating the table means that every piece of code that refers to this table will always-and-forevermore HAVE to quote the name. This leads to confusion, misunderstanding, and annoyance. Don't. Just, don't. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is:

```
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
```

The reason is: [`VARCHAR2`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1821) needs a length parameter to define the maximum column length, like

```
 first_name VARCHAR2(100),
```

Answer (score 2):

The `VARCHAR2` type requires a length parameter:

```
CREATE TABLE "employee_copy" (
   employee_id    NUMBER(10), 
   first_name     VARCHAR2(50), 
   last_name      VARCHAR2(50), 
   email          VARCHAR2(50), 
   phone_number   VARCHAR2(50), 
   hire_date      DATE, 
   job_id         VARCHAR2(50), 
   salary         NUMBER(10), 
   commission_pct NUMBER(3,3), 
   manager_id     NUMBER(10),
   department_id  NUMBER(10)
)
```

Also, formatting your statement enhances its readability considerably.

Answer (score -1):

Table naming like "employee_copy" is not relevant approach because you use quoted lower-case table name.
Take into account what Oracle uses upper-case treatment of identifiers by default.
So if you use lower-case or mixed case + quotation Oracle will ignore the same name without quotation:

```
SQL> create table "employee_copy" (x int);

Таблица создана.

SQL> select * from employee_copy;
select * from employee_copy
              *
Error at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

SQL> select * from  "employee_copy";

No rows selected
```